# How does Spring 3 map the form-post in this jsp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

At [line 17 of `login.jsp`](http://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/login.jsp#L17), there is the following line of code:

```
<form action="/login/submit" method="post">
```

What I can't determine is where Spring submits this form to.

In [the corresponding `LoginController.java`](http://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jappstart/controller/LoginController.java), I don't see any mapping to the URL '`/login/submit`' such as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

So how does Spring 3 know what to do with this form action?

UPDATE:

Found this [here](http://github.com/tleese22/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml#L21):

```
<form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login/submit" authentication-failure-url="/login/error" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the login processing URL takes care of handling this form POST. If you look further in the security context file (most likely the file where you found the form-login element) you should see an authentication manager and a user details service which will tell you how Spring knows which credentials are authentic.

Answer (score 2):

Spring 3 only "knows" what you tell it to, either through your XML configuration or annotations.

Your question is really "Where do I have `/login/submit` mapped to a controller?", and without your code, we cannot answer any of this.

Are you using Spring Security, which may have a login-form mapped to this URL? If so, examine your Spring Security context XML file.

Otherwise, turn up `DEBUG` logging within Spring and upon server startup it will map out each URL that is mapped to each controller.

Comment: Yes, I just found a security reference. I will update the question.